# Is it possible to see history of command blocks oín minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

So one of people i know said that somehow it is possible to see command block history (by that i mean commands that were there and then deleted/replaced) So i just wonder if it's possible. I cant find anywhere on internet that it is

Answer (score 1):

No. In a Singleplayer World it is not possible.
But in a Multiplayer World, you probably can access the Commands in the Console History.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you can. I'm afraid I don not know what setting enables this. But when I use commandblocks, the commands are always put in the chat saying something along the lines of : Command block was changed to: *my command here*